# How to hide or manipulate a control inside a ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a `textbox` control and a `button` control inside a `listview`, I want to hide those controls when required from code behind, I have tried using something like this

```
ListViewName.FindControl("TextBoxComment").Visible = false;
```

and

```
((TextBox)ListViewName.FindControl("TextBoxComment")).Visible = false
```

but when I run the code it gives `NullReference Exception`

Please help.

```
 <ItemTemplate>
          <table>

               <tr>
                   <td>
                       <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxComment" runat="server" >
                       </asp:TextBox>
                   </td>

                   <td>
                       <asp:Button ID="ButtonSubmit" runat="server"  
                            CommandName="Comment" 
                            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("FlowPostID") %>'/>
                   </td>
                </tr>
          </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: On which event you want to hide the controls?

Comment: @Shekhar Item COmmand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this, it worked

```
TextBox Box = new TextBox()

Button Butt = new Button();

Box = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("TextBoxComment")
Butt = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("ButtonSubmit")

Box.Visible = false;
```

That worked perfectly fine :) Thank you all for your effort :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this on the ListView's ItemDataBound Event Handle.

```
var item = (ListViewItem)e.DataItem;

var txtBox = (txtBox)item.FindControl("TextBoxComment");

if(txtBox != null)
{
  txtBox.Visible = false;
}
```

And so forth...

Comment: what does this ItemDataBound does , please explain.

Comment: The on ItemDataBound event lets you handle each item in Item-Template  as they are  bound to the Listview. You use it to modify the state of controls where there is a requirement to use logic to set the properties of the controls. for example, the css or wether the control is deemed visible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the null values

```
var textbox=ListViewName.FindControl("TextBoxComment");
if(textbox!=null)
    ListViewName.FindControl("TextBoxComment").Visible = false;
```

Comment: but my ListView has those controls, still why it is showing nullreference error ?

Comment: Because they are created at the Run-Time. And you might be calling it before it is creaded.